# Ending OpenMP for prematurely

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a problem with writing a routine in C++ using OpenMP for. The code of the routine is as follows:

```
int sudokuSolution [9][9];

bool solvep(int s[9][9], int row, int col) {    
    bool solution = false;
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int val = 1; val < 10; val++) {
            if (isPossible(s,row,col,val)) {
                s[row][col] = val;  
                if (solve(s, row + col / 9, (col + 1) % 9)) {
                    sudokuSolution[row][col] = val;
                    solution = true;
                }
            }
        }
    return solution;
}
```

when running this routine without the parallel clause, everything works fine (i.e. routine returns `true` every time it's called). However, when I use the parallel for, it sometimes returns `false`. I wasn't able to figure out, why is this happening and the only way of removing this bug is from my perspective ending the whole parallel block prematurely after solution is set to `true`. However, if I did my research properly, there is no way to prematurely end a parallel block. Could you please suggest me an alternative?

EDIT: Adding minimal functioning example as requested:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

bool solutionFound = false;
int sudoku [9][9] = { 5,7,0,9,0,0,0,0,8,
                      0,0,0,0,0,5,0,3,9,
                      0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,4,
                      0,0,0,0,9,0,6,8,0,
                      0,0,0,8,0,2,0,0,0,
                      0,5,2,0,7,0,0,0,0,
                      6,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                      7,9,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,
                      2,0,0,0,0,9,0,7,6};

int sudokuSolution [9][9];

bool isPossible(int s[9][9], int row, int col, int val) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (s[row][i] == val)
            return false;
        if (s[i][col] == val)
            return false;
        if (s[row / 3 * 3 + i / 3][col / 3 * 3 + i % 3] == val)
            return false;
    }       
    return true;
}

bool solve(int s[9][9], int row, int col) { 
    while(s[row][col] != 0) {
        col = (col + 1) % 9;
        row = row + col / 8;
        if(row == 9)        
            return true;
    }   

    for (int val = 1; val < 10; val++) {
        if (isPossible(s,row,col,val)){
            sudokuSolution[row][col] = val;
            s[row][col] = val;
            if (solve(s, row + col / 9, (col + 1) % 9))
                return true;
            sudokuSolution[row][col] = 0;
            s[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


bool solvep(int sa[9][9], int row, int col) {   
    int s [9][9];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            s[i][j] = sa[i][j];
    while(s[row][col] != 0) {
        col = (col + 1) % 9;
        row = row + col / 8;
        if(row == 9)        
            return true;
    }   
    bool solution = false;
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int val = 1; val < 10; val++) {
            if(!solutionFound) {
                if (isPossible(s,row,col,val)){
                    s[row][col] = val;  
                    if (solve(s, row + col / 9, (col + 1) % 9)) {
                        sudokuSolution[row][col] = val;
                        solutionFound = true;
                        solution = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return solution;
}

int main() {
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {     
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                sudokuSolution[i][j] = sudoku[i][j];
        solutionFound = false;      
        solvep(sudokuSolution,0,0); 
        bool calcResult = solvep(sudoku,0,0);   
        cout << calcResult;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at cancellation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22173656/620382 Your code regarding `solution` is technically incorrect (`solution = true` should be marked `atomic`), but this is probably not the reason for your issue. Besides what you see, there are multiple race conditions when writing to `s` and `sudokuSolution`. For actual debugging help, please add a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at cancelation. Is it a good idea to try to avoid the race conditions with `#pragma omp critical` or would it be too bad for the performance? I've added the example of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You have many race conditions in your code, both in the loop itself and the `solve` function. In code that is executed in parallel you must not write to to shared data (`s`, `solution`, `sudokuSolution`) and especially global variables (`solutionFound`). You will have to go back to your learning material and catch up with data races and the methods to protect against them.

With some experience it is easy to spot the issues in the loop itself. It's much harder to spot in called functions - which is why its so important to give a complete example in your question. Try to define your interfaces such that mutable no shared data is passed to functions. Conceptually you will have to have a copy of the board for each thread to perform backtracking in parallel.

Once you fix the issues with writing to the board, you can use atomic writes, a critical region or a reduction to "share" the solution. But you have to consider both `sudokuSolution[row][col]` and `solution`. Logically I suppose `sudokuSolution[row][col] != 0 == solution`.

Answer (score 0):

You could [reduce](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/omp-reduction.html) the solution values on all threads using the `||` operator:

```
int sudokuSolution [9][9];

bool solvep(int s[9][9], int row, int col) {    
    bool solution = false;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(||:solution)
        for (int val = 1; val < 10; val++) {
            if (isPossible(s,row,col,val)) {
                s[row][col] = val;  
                if (solve(s, row + col / 9, (col + 1) % 9)) {
                    sudokuSolution[row][col] = val;
                    solution = true;
                } else {
                    solution = false;
                } 
            } else {
                 solution = false;
            }
        }
    return solution;
}
```

Comment: I think the `solution = false` branches are wrong. Also there's still two race conditions (note how `row`/`col` is the same for each thread).

Comment: The `solution = false` branches are right. Did you read the linked article about the semantics of `reduction`? Reduction transforms the shared variable `solution` into a local variable for each thread, which are combined in the end. There can be no race conditions on `row` and `col`, because they are only read, not written to in the parallel section. Immutable state can safely be shared between threads, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: 1) Each thread (can) run multiple iterations of the loop, hence overwriting it's private copy of previous iterations. Fortunately you can just skip it because the private copy for `reduction(||)` is initialized with `0`. 2) The race condition is on `sudokuSolution[row][col]` (and many more on `s` inside `solve`). I was referring to `row`/`col` because something like `x[row][col]` is usually not suspicious if the parallel loop is on either `row` or `col`.